# 415 unsupported media type content-type application/pgp-encrypted while sending POST message

Tags: postman, binaryfiles, content-type, rest, pgp

I'm working in REST API development project. The client have provided the OpenAPI specification for the API which they are expecting.

We have used the openAPI generator cli to generate the API from the OpenAPI specs given by the client.
Following are the two APIs

**1. /requestFile:**

This API is expected to accept JSON payload and produces payload of content type application/pgp-encrypted.
We have annotated the API as below.

```
@postmapping(value="/requestFile",consumes={"application/json"},produces={"application/pgp-encrypted"})
```

The expectation is to transfer a PGP encrypted JSON file as a response to the POST message.

I'm not sure how to transfer the PGP encrypted file as a response, I have searched for some references but most of them are using maultipart file to transfer binary files. Whereas the content type of multipartfiles is not same as "application/pgp-encrypted".

I need some help in transferring this pgp encrypted file as a response to the POST message via REST API.

**2. /feedback**

This API consumes payload of type application/pgp-encrypted and produces a simple http response code back to the client. We have annotated the API as below.

```
@postmapping(value="/feedback", consumes={"application/pgp-encrypted"})
```

When I try to send a POST message using POSTMAN with content type application/pgp-encrypted, we are getting a 415 unsupported mediatype error.

I need to understand how do we send pgp-encrypted file as a payload via POSTMAN and what is the content type I must use to achieve this.

Comment: I have got some reference regarding content type: application/pgp-encrypted from https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

Comment: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3156